# How to send a WebSocket close frame to the client on PHP server?

Tags: php, websocket

I've wrote this code in the close method of a WebSocekt class:

```
$msg = str_split(sprintf('%016b', $code), 8);
$msg[0] = chr(bindec($msg[0]));
$msg[1] = chr(bindec($msg[1]));
$msg = implode('', $msg).$reason;
socket_write($client, self::encode($msg, 'close'), 127);
```

What I now sure is that I've wrote it according to what I was told on the protocol page, the method encode() has created a close frame, socket_write() sent it to the client with no mistake, neither the server nor the client reported any errors. But the client received nothing, when using console.log() to log the onclose event, it reported closing uncleanly, and got a close code 1006, with no reason, even though I sent close frame with code 1000 and a reason of normal close. So I got confused, who can tell me how to send a close frame that will make this work.

Comment: And what WebSocket library are you using?

Comment: I myself write the library, that's why I get this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. Sending socket.close(1000, 'Your reason') doesn't make the client receive a close control frame. You'll have to do that on the back-end also using socket_close($client). Nevertheless, although, this closes the connection, it doesn't send a close control frame to the client. I suspect this has something to do with making sure the socket_close($client) waits, then do something about it when appropriate. Therefore something like socket_set_options() with SO_LINGER may work. I am still investigating on this issue.